# List taxonomies according to whether this post is in another taxonomy in taxonomy archive

Tags: custom-taxonomy, archives

I have two taxonomies for categories of custom post type 'items'; 'type' and 'group'. They are not exclusive so one hierarchical taxonomy won't work although to an extent, as you'll see, they are hierarchical. So, for instance, I have a group 'group1' which may be in more than one type.

What I need to do is produce a taxonomy page 'type1' that list all the 'groups' with 'type1. It's easy enough to produce a list of posts in 'group1' but I don't know how to list the 'groups' that contain 'items' with type 'type1'.

I can see the logic but I'm struggling to produce the code. As these questions work better with some code, I'll update as I go.

This is on a page taxonomy-type.php;

```
// First get the type
$term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) );
$type = $term->slug;
// loop through all 'type1' posts 
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
   // get all the terms for 'group'
   $group_terms = get_terms( 'group' );
   //print_r($group_terms);
   // loop through all the terms;
   foreach ($group_terms as $group_term) :
     // if this post in in our taxonomy list it
     if (has_term($group_term, 'group') {
       echo"<li>".$group_term->name."</li>";
     }
   endforeach;
endwhile;
```

Produces the term followed by the item (much the same as the taxonomy archive would without my help!)

Comment: if 'type' and 'group' are 2 taxonomies, there is no group with type1. or maybe you added code to do that ? or you want to search groups which are connected to items which are associated to type1 ?

Comment: Please feel free to edit the title if it can make more sense

Comment: @mmm I want to list groups in type1 if they exist (eventually all types will be none-empty) it's items that can be in group1 and type1 (and must be in at least one of each) but I need to list the groups not the items - does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Well I got there, my public brain functions for all to see, hopefully someone somewhen will pass this was and find it useful.

The code;

```
// First get the type
$term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) );
$type = $term->slug;
// we need to do some comparisons, here's the variable
 $this_instance = "";
// loop through all 'type1' posts 
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
 $group_terms = get_terms( 'group' );
 //print_r($group_terms);
 // then loop through all terms for this post
 foreach ($group_terms as $group_term) :
   if (has_term($group_term, 'group')) {
     $first_instance = $group_term->slug;
     // if this is the first do something
     if ($this_instance !== $first_instance) { ?>
       <li><?= $group_term->name; ?></li>
        <? $this_instance = $first_instance;
      }
    }
  endforeach;
endwhile;
```